# Create iOS framework that calls methods for the end user automatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, frameworks

hey i have a iOS question, Im starting to create a framework, right now its just one class with one method

```
open class MyFramework: NSObject {
    open class func verifySell() -> Bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

so the user of this framework can just simply use this like so in their app wherever they want

```
import UIKit
import MyFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let canSell = MyFramework.verifySell()
        print("MyFramework can sell = \(canSell)")
    }


}
```

is there a way that this framework im making can tie into lifecycle events?

I want it to automatically call this method on app start up, or when it comes back from the foreground etc. So the developer basically only has to install the framework and it does it for them. The developer wont have to worry about calling this method in their own code (edited)

or do you think its a better api design to have the developer call framework methods  wherever they see fit?

eventually this verifySell() method will make a network call that returns true for false if we can sell to a customer, and then ill probably have the framework store that somewhere in NSUserDefaults somehow

Comment: "eventually this verifySell() method will make a network call that returns true for false if we can sell to a customer, and then ill probably have the framework store that somewhere in NSUserDefaults somehow" surely the SDK users will need to pass certain information to this method for it to have enough information to make a decision, so it would be best for the SDK user to call it and pass any required information.

Comment: could the framework just grab some kind of unique identifier like a token out of nsuserdefaults or something?

Comment: *if* it was set. I think its much better for the user of the framework to call it and pass parameters, then they know what information is being sent and when. if you try to trigger it automatically the timing might be wrong, the data might not have been set etc

Comment: in any case, IS there a way to have this method called automatically?

Comment: Not really... I mean in a normal app you could just listen for certain notifications to be posted and react accordingly, but for that to work you need to start listening for those notifications, without the user calling any of your code, none of your code will run to start this off. At some point a user needs to call something on your framework for it to do anything. even if thats just a register or initialise call.